# Apache Rewrite module, complex rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I basically want to redirect all requests to index.php doesn't matter what, except those with certain `REQUEST_URI`. Those requests that look like image files, so have an ending like: `.jpg` or `.png` should be examined and if they are under the `public/` folder (or any subfolders in any depth) and if they are they should be served and the rewriting process should stop here! If not, I want to redirect to a default image at `public/errors/image-not-found.png` and terminate rewriting process. The other exceptions are files that end with `.js, .css, .html` or `.swf`. They also should only be served if they are located under the `public/` folder or any other subfolders. If not, a simple `404-Not found` should be sent back. In either case of the last to the rewriting process need to stop of course.
Any other request should be redirected to `index.php` and appended as a `query string`. (even if the request points to a directory or to a file that is not under the conditions aforesaid, but exists, e.g: `www.xyz.com/library/Database.php` -> `www.xyz.com/index.php?url=library/Database.php`)

I have half-measure solution:
This is how I redirect everything to index.php:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I append a visual explanation of what I want. Maybe this is clearer: [image: flowchart]

Comment: What you request seems unnecessarily complex, and also synonimizes an endless amount of urls to the same existing image or stylesheet, or html file, potentially causing duplicate content warnings and penalizing in search engines. "Is it located under x or **any random subfolder**" is a wrong way of approaching this I think.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you don't want to do anything if the requested file exists in `public/` or any of its subfolders. So, first we deal with those:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public/.*\.(html|css|js|swf|jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Now, that is over with. We now check whether an image was requested:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /public/errors/image-not-found.png [R,L]
```

Similarly for other static files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(html|css|js|swf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Redirect everything now to `index.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php?url=$0 [R,L]
```

Comment: The problem is that when I request an image that exists under the public (`public/test.jpg` or `public/images/test.jpg`), it is redirected to the `/public/errors/image-not-found.png`

Answer (score 0):

Following series of rules should probably mimic the flow-chart:

```
# for public folder pass through
RewriteRule ^public/.+?\.(?:jpe?g|ico|png|bmp|css|js|html|swf)$ - [L,NC]

# for other images
RewriteRule ^.+?\.(?:jpe?g|ico|png|bmp)$ /public/errors/img-not-found.jpg [L,NC,R=302]

# for other css|js|html|swf URIs
RewriteRule ^.+?\.(?:css|js|html|swf)$ - [L,NC,R=404]

# everything else, route to index.php
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).+)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```