# Rewrite loop won't stop

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a `.htaccess` file that should redirect all requests to `index.php?url=$1`, Except if the request points to images or specific files. If these are located somewhere undetr the `public/` folder they should be served. If the requested file is an image somewhere out of the `public/` folder then it is redirected to a default image, and if the requested file is a HTML, JS, CSS, SWF file and is out of the `public/` folder a simle `404-not found` should be sent back.
Everything works good except that when I request images from `/public` or let's say `public/images` they are redirected to the default image as well. I've tried everything, even the `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` but still the same. Any Ideas how could I make the loop stop If the file has been served in the line 11.?

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE on
    RewriteBase /wsproject/

    Options All -Indexes
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^public/.*\.(html|css|js|swf|jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|ico)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|ico)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ public/errors/img-not-found.png [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(html|css|js|swf)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public/.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I use the code from a former answer, you can see here: [Apache Rewrite module, complex rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847302/apache-rewrite-module-complex-rules/32849304#32849304)

Answer (score 0):

Use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI` as your last rule is rewriting everything to `/index.php` and changing value of `REQUEST_URI`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE on
    RewriteBase /wsproject/

    Options All -Indexes
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/.+?\.(html|css|js|swf|jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|ico)\s [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|ico)\s [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ public/errors/img-not-found.png [L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(html|css|js|swf)\s [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/public/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```